# Confusion in the answers given by mathematica

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, wolfram-alpha

When I typed in

> 6^-1 mod 49 in Wolfram|Alpha, it gave me an answer of 41. [Link here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%206%5E-1%20mod%2049)
>
> If I type the same thing as (1/6) mod 49 , I don't see 41 any more. Why is this happening ?[Link here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281/6%29%20mod%2049)

A Related question :

> How is the answer to  6^-1 mod 49 , **41** in the first place ?

A small change in the above question :

If the question is find , 9^-2 mod 49, what are the steps to find the answer ?

Comment: $6\times41=246=245+1=(5)(49)+1\equiv1\pmod{49}$

Comment: You can use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find the modular inverse of $81$, $\bmod 49$. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).

Answer (score 3):

The $41$ is because $6\times 41=246=1\bmod 49$.

I assume that what's happening is that if you type $(1/6)$ instead, it assumes that you're happy to work with rational numbers rather than just integers and gives you back $1/6$.

Comment: In short: `Mod[1/6, 49]` and `PowerMod[6, -1, 49]` are two different things.